# How to fill a rounded rectangle in openCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, draw, rounded-corners

I figure a way to draw a rounded rectangle using OpenCV C++. My function is:

```
void RoundedRectangle(cv::Mat& src, 
                      cv::Point topLeft, 
                      cv::Size rectSz, 
                      const cv::Scalar lineColor, 
                      const int thickness, 
                      const int lineType, 
                      const float  cornerCurvatureRatio)
{
    // corners:
    // p1 - p2
    // |     |
    // p4 - p3
    //
    cv::Point p1 = topLeft;
    cv::Point p2 = cv::Point (p1.x + rectSz.width, p1.y);
    cv::Point p3 = cv::Point (p1.x + rectSz.width, p1.y + rectSz.height);
    cv::Point p4 = cv::Point (p1.x, p1.y + rectSz.height);
    float cornerRadius = rectSz.height*cornerCurvatureRatio;

    // draw straight lines
    cv::line(src, cv::Point (p1.x + cornerRadius, p1.y), cv::Point (p2.x - cornerRadius, p2.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::line(src, cv::Point (p2.x, p2.y + cornerRadius), cv::Point (p3.x, p3.y - cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::line(src, cv::Point (p4.x + cornerRadius, p4.y), cv::Point (p3.x - cornerRadius, p3.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::line(src, cv::Point (p1.x, p1.y + cornerRadius), cv::Point (p4.x, p4.y - cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);

     // draw arcs
    cv::Size rad = cv::Size(cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    cv::ellipse(src, p1 + cv::Point(cornerRadius, cornerRadius),   rad, 180.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::ellipse(src, p2 + cv::Point(-cornerRadius, cornerRadius),  rad, 270.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::ellipse(src, p3 + cv::Point(-cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), rad, 0.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    cv::ellipse(src, p4 + cv::Point(cornerRadius, -cornerRadius),  rad, 90.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType);
}
```

Now I want to fill the rectangle. I found some fill functions such as `cv::fillPoly() and cv::fillConvexPoly` however, I need a vector with points. How I can get the list of points from my construction?

Comment: If I interpret this [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) correctly, passing a negative thickness to `cv::ellipse` *" indicates that a filled ellipse sector is to be drawn"*. So you could draw the four "corners" and then fill the reamaining "cross" (as rectangles).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I try this, but it will not fill the whole contour. Just the rounded corners where the partial ellipse is drawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuzhny was correct, `floodFill()` is the easiest and potentially the fastest way to fill that rounded rectangle. (Tested with CV 4.1.1)

One line of code will do it, but here is the entire example.

```
void rounded_rectangle( Mat& src, Point topLeft, Point bottomRight, const Scalar lineColor, int thickness, const int lineType , const int cornerRadius)
{
    Point p1 = topLeft;
    Point p2 = Point (bottomRight.x, topLeft.y);
    Point p3 = bottomRight;
    Point p4 = Point (topLeft.x, bottomRight.y);


    line(src, Point (p1.x+cornerRadius,p1.y), Point (p2.x-cornerRadius,p2.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p2.x,p2.y+cornerRadius), Point (p3.x,p3.y-cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p4.x+cornerRadius,p4.y), Point (p3.x-cornerRadius,p3.y), lineColor, thickness, lineType);
    line(src, Point (p1.x,p1.y+cornerRadius), Point (p4.x,p4.y-cornerRadius), lineColor, thickness, lineType);

    ellipse( src, p1+Point(cornerRadius, cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 180.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p2+Point(-cornerRadius, cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 270.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p3+Point(-cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 0.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );
    ellipse( src, p4+Point(cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), Size( cornerRadius, cornerRadius ), 90.0, 0, 90, lineColor, thickness, lineType );

    // choose arbitrary starting point for fill => Top left plus 10,10
    Point fillFrom(topLeft.x+10, topLeft.y+10);
    Scalar fillColor(199, 120, 0);
    // You may want to use `lineColor` instead of `fillColor`
    floodFill(src, fillFrom, fillColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the points from the shape that you constructed with `cv::line` and `cv::ellipse` , you could draw the shape on a black background and then find the contours of that image.

Another approach that doesn't use `line` and `ellipse` commands is to compute the contour of the shape directly using trig.

[image: rectangle being drawn]

```
import cv2, numpy as np, math

# Define the rectangle parameters
directions, ro, next_corner, radius, increment, angle, leg, corners = [(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)],[(-1,-1),(1,-1),(1,1),(-1,1)],[3,0,1,2],56, 100, 0, 321, [(500,500)]

# Create list of corners
for side in range(4): corners.append((corners[side][0]+leg*directions[side][0], corners[side][1]+leg*directions[side][1]))

# Distance function
def distance(a,b): return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)

# Compute the contour points for each side and corner
contour_points = []
for i in range(4):
    # Do the corner
    center = corners[i][0] + radius*ro[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*ro[i][1]
    for angle_increment in range(increment):
        contour_points.append((int(center[0] + math.cos(angle) * radius), int(center[1] + math.sin(angle) * radius)))
        angle += .5*math.pi/increment
    # Do the line
    start = corners[i][0]+radius*directions[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*directions[i][1]
    while distance(start, (corners[i][0]+radius*directions[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*directions[i][1])) < leg-2*radius:
        contour_points.append(start)
        start = start[0]+directions[i][0], start[1]+directions[i][1]

# Draw the contour and show the image
img = np.zeros((600,600), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(img, [np.array(contour_points, dtype=np.int32)], 0, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why use `math` for math functions when you already have numpy imported? Also, it is recommended against multiple imports on one line, so I would refrain from putting that into answers, and similarly you should probably indent your code blocks and refrain from one-lining everything. More concisely, I would suggest to try and conform your code to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when giving answers to nudge code towards being slightly more helpful to newbies. The answer and gif is great otherwise, btw.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me. This is a clever way to do this. My function need to be in C++, but I talk python too. However, my info is the left corner point and size of the box. With this code it is difficult for me to see how to use that info. I am analysing it  and looks like this will draw rounded squares of side equal to ``leg``. ``corner`` is the right lower corner of the square. I found a different way to solve this. However I will take the time to rework this to suit my purposes and publish it here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use cv::floodFill with start point inside your rectangle.

Comment: I am creating a rounded rectangle by partilly drawing each of its edges. I am not sure I can use that function without creating some kind of contour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in case id of help to anybody.

```
void FilledRoundedRectangle(cv::Mat& src,            //Image where rect is drawn
                      cv::Point topLeft,             //top left corner
                      cv::Size rectSz,               //rectangle size
                      const cv::Scalar fillColor,    //fill color
                      const int lineType,            //type of line
                      const int delta,               //angle between points on the ellipse
                      const float cornerCurvatureRatio) //curvature of the corner
{
    // corners:
    // p1 - p2
    // |     |
    // p4 - p3
    //
    cv::Point p1 = topLeft;
    cv::Point p2 = cv::Point (p1.x + rectSz.width, p1.y);
    cv::Point p3 = cv::Point (p1.x + rectSz.width, p1.y + rectSz.height);
    cv::Point p4 = cv::Point (p1.x, p1.y + rectSz.height);
    int cornerRadius = static_cast<int>(rectSz.height*cornerCurvatureRatio);
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    std::vector<cv::Point> pts;
    // Add arcs points

    cv::Size rad = cv::Size(cornerRadius, cornerRadius);

    // segments:
    //    s2____s3
    // s1          s4
    // |           |
    // s8          s5
    //   s7_____s6
    //
    //Add arc s1 to s2 
    cv::ellipse2Poly(p1 + cv::Point(cornerRadius, cornerRadius)  , rad, 180.0, 0, 90, delta , pts);
    points.insert(points.end(), pts.begin(), pts.end());
    pts.clear();
    //Add line s2-s3 
    points.push_back(cv::Point (p1.x + cornerRadius, p1.y)); points.push_back(cv::Point (p2.x - cornerRadius, p2.y));

    //Add arc s3 to s4 
    cv::ellipse2Poly(p2 + cv::Point(-cornerRadius, cornerRadius) , rad, 270.0, 0, 90, delta, pts);
    points.insert(points.end(), pts.begin(), pts.end());
    pts.clear();
    //Add line s4 to s5
    points.push_back(cv::Point (p2.x, p2.y + cornerRadius)); points.push_back(cv::Point (p3.x, p3.y - cornerRadius));

    //Add arc s5 to s6 
    cv::ellipse2Poly(p3 + cv::Point(-cornerRadius, -cornerRadius), rad, 0.0,   0, 90, delta, pts);
    points.insert(points.end(), pts.begin(), pts.end());
    pts.clear();
    //Add line s7 to s8
    points.push_back(cv::Point (p4.x + cornerRadius, p4.y)); points.push_back(cv::Point (p3.x - cornerRadius, p3.y));

    //Add arc s7 to s8 
    cv::ellipse2Poly(p4 + cv::Point(cornerRadius, -cornerRadius) , rad, 90.0,  0, 90, delta, pts);
    points.insert(points.end(), pts.begin(), pts.end());
    //Add line s1 to s8
    points.push_back(cv::Point (p1.x, p1.y + cornerRadius)); points.push_back(cv::Point (p4.x, p4.y - cornerRadius));    

    //fill polygon
    cv::fillConvexPoly(src, points, fillColor, lineType);
}


   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
      try
      {
          cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(600, 600,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(0));
          cv::Point topLeft(179, 179);
          cv::Size rectSz(321, 321);
          cv::Scalar fillColor(255, 255, 255);
          int delta                  = 1; //every 1 degree
          int lineType               = cv::LINE_AA;
          float cornerCurvatureRatio = 0.1;
          FilledRoundedRectangle(img,
                                 topLeft,
                                 rectSz,
                                 fillColor,
                                 lineType,
                                 delta,
                                 cornerCurvatureRatio);
          cv::imshow("", img);
          cv::waitKey(0);
         return 0;
         std::cin.get();
      } //end try
      catch ( std::exception const & ex )
      {
         std::string errMsg = ex.what();
         printf( "%s\n", errMsg.c_str() );
      }
      catch ( ... )
      {
         printf( "Error: unknown exception\n" );
      }



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a generalization of the answer submitted by @Stephen Meschke in case anyone is interested

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Distance function
def distance(a,b): 
    return np.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)

def RoundedRectPoints(topLeft,rectSz,cornerCurvature):
    # Define the rectangle parameters
    directions  = [(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)]
    ro          = [(-1,-1),(1,-1),(1,1),(-1,1)]
    radius      = cornerCurvature*(rectSz[0]+rectSz[1]);
    increment   = 100
    angle       = 0
    corners     = [(topLeft[0]+rectSz[0],topLeft[1]+rectSz[1])]

    # Create list of corners
    for side in range(4): 
        corners.append((corners[side][0]+rectSz[side%2]*directions[side][0], corners[side][1]+rectSz[side%2]*directions[side][1]))

    # Compute the contour points for each side and corner
    contour_points = []
    for i in range(4):
        # Do the corner
        center = corners[i][0] + radius*ro[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*ro[i][1]
        for angle_increment in range(increment):
            contour_points.append((int(center[0] + np.cos(angle) * radius), int(center[1] + np.sin(angle) * radius)))
            angle += .5*np.pi/increment
        # Do the line
        start = corners[i][0]+radius*directions[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*directions[i][1]
        while distance(start, (corners[i][0]+radius*directions[i][0], corners[i][1] + radius*directions[i][1])) < np.min(rectSz)-2*radius:
            contour_points.append(start)
            start = start[0]+directions[i][0], start[1]+directions[i][1]
    return contour_points

# Draw the contour and show the image
img = np.zeros((600,600), np.uint8)
topLeft = (179,179)
rectSz = (321,321)
cornerCurvature = 0.09
contour_points = RoundedRectPoints(topLeft,rectSz,cornerCurvature)
cv2.drawContours(img, [np.array(contour_points, dtype=np.int32)], 0, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for rewriting the code that I posted. It looks so much cleaner!